# Output of Hive extract to local drive error

Tags: hive

i have created a directory in hdfs as Test, but when i trying to insert records
from hive to the hdfs it is throwing error as

```
Error: WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'

WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/HDP.list'

INSERT: command not found
```

Command i used

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/Test' select * from table limit 10
```

Please help

Comment: the directory should point to a directory on the server, not your local machine.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala: is there anyway to see current directory

Comment: sure..if you are on Beeline (Hive command line interface) / on the server.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala: i am using putty

Comment: Hi @RohiniMathur, and in putty you launch directly the insert overwrite statement?

Comment: @F.Lazarescu.Yes Exactly.... kindly suggest if I am missing anything